# how to convert reverse geocode result to english?

Tags: node.js, openstreetmap

My reverse geocode result contains some of sinhalese language. I want completely English result to be dispalyed. how should that be done?

Comment: The answer depends on the specific geocoder you are using. Unfortunately you haven't told us the name of your geocoder. Usually you want to configure it to return results in a specific language.

Comment: cross-post: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/69547/how-to-convert-reverse-goecode-result-to-english